# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL for twitter picture returning nil when same thing works for instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, asynchronous

Im trying to display twitter pictures but dataWithContentsOfString is returning nil when the same exact thing works for an instagram photo url. It works when I use the actual url instead of getting it from the nsdictionary

```
NSString *twitterString = @"http://pbs.twimg.com/media/BYWHiq1IYAAwSCR.jpg"
```

but not like this

```
if ([post valueForKeyPath:@"entities.media.media_url"]) {
        NSString *twitterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [post valueForKeyPath:@"entities.media.media_url"]];
        NSURL *twitterPhotoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:twitterString];
        dispatch_queue_t queue = kBgQueue;
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:twitterPhotoUrl];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [streamPhotoArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:image];
                cell.twitterPhoto.image = image;
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you make a NSLog to show what comes on : "[post valueForKeyPath:@"entities.media.media_url"]" ?

Comment: i get... [Line 405] ("http://pbs.twimg.com/media/BYWHiq1IYAAwSCR.jpg")

Comment: for some reason stack overflow is cutting off the http:// at the beginning

Comment: Use `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` so you can see what the error is.

Comment: Yeah Ive tried that. It says nil URL argument. I've googled that error but couldn't find anything helpful

Comment: Try logging the length of both of your twitterStrings, the direct url and what you get back from the dictionary to make sure there are no hidden characters that make the 2 strings different.

Comment: I found out that there are hidden characters and have asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872010/nsutf8stringencoding-gives-me-this-0a2020202022http-example-com-example