# NSUTF8StringEncoding gives me this %0A%20%20%20%20%22http://example.com/example.jpg%22%0A

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring, nsurl

I'm trying to load pictures from twitter. If i just use the URL in the json results without encoding, in the `dataWithContentsOfURL`, I get nil URL argument. If I encode it, I get as follow's

> %0A%20%20%20%20%22http://example.com/example.jpg%22%0A.

I know I can use `rangeOfString:` or `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` but can I be sure that it will always be the same, is there another way to handle this, and why is this happening to my twitter response and not my instagram response?

I have also tried

```
stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]
```

and it does nothing.

This is the URL directly from the json...

```
2013-11-08 22:09:31:812 JaVu[1839:1547] -[SingleEventTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 406] (
    "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/BYWHiq1IYAAwSCR.jpg"
)
```

Here is my code

```
if ([post valueForKeyPath:@"entities.media.media_url"]) {
        NSString *twitterString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [post valueForKeyPath:@"entities.media.media_url"]]stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        twitterString = [twitterString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", twitterString);

        if (twitterString != nil){
            NSURL *twitterPhotoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:twitterString];
            NSLog(@"%@", twitterPhotoUrl);
            dispatch_queue_t queue = kBgQueue;
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                NSError *error;
                NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:twitterPhotoUrl options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [streamPhotoArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:image];
                    cell.instagramPhoto.image = image;
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You asked a similar question about 3 hours ago, the same URL.

Comment: Yes it is similar but its a different question because now I know why dataWithContentsOfURL is returning nil. My new question is how to get rid of the extra characters

Comment: Your question is very unclear. The log output you show appears to be an array, since it has parentheses with the string on a separate line. You shouldn't need to encode the string if it's already a valid URL string and in fact doing so is wrong and will break things. I think you have misunderstood your data structure.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Im still new to this. But you were right. It was an array for some reason. Adding objectAtIndex:0 fixed the problem. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it as the answer. Although I'm still curious as to why it would be an array. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log output you show appears to be an array, since it has parentheses with the string on a separate line.

You shouldn't need to encode the string if it's already a valid URL string and in fact doing so is wrong and will break things.

Comment: You were right, it is an array. I added objectAtIndex:0 and it fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

`%0A%20%20%20%20%22` stands for a `\n` followed by 4 spaces and then `"`. This is in accordance with the description in the console. Have you used `NSJSONSerialization` to obtain the URL from JSON data?

Comment: Yes i did use NSJSONSerialization

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer rather a step in solving the error,: Change your code to this and post the output.  Combining several method calls in one makes debugging harder.

```
NSLog(@"post: '%@", post);
NSString * twitterString;
twitterString = [post valueForKeyPath:@"entities.media.media_url"];
NSLog(@"twitterString 1: '%@", twitterString);
twitterString = [twitterString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"twitterString 2: '%@", twitterString);
        twitterString = [twitterString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"twitterString 3: '%@", twitterString);
```

BTW, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"...` is not necessary.

Comment: That code will blow up. The use of `-stringWithFormat:` was "necessary" in this case because `[post valueForKeyPath:@"entities.media.media_url"]` wasn't returning a string, it was returning an array. Of course, that meant it only masked the original error. In that sense, your code blowing up would be a valuable diagnostic.

Comment: @Ken As I state, this is not production code, rather just a way to figure out what is wrong. I posted as an answer because comments do not have code formatting. As you state, the `-stringWithFormat:` was actually masking the problem and not doing what the OP thought. The compound line of code also makes finding the problem harder, breaking it up and eliminating the `-stringWithFormat:` makes it easier to find the problem.